# Two horizontal rules made by \hrule in the same line

Tags: tables, tex-core, boxes

I make a table by the following code in which a cell of the talbe is consctructed by a `\makebox`. Cells at the same line are seperated by `\vrule`. lines are seperated by `\hrule`.

In this example, I want horizontal rules made by `\hrule` to appear at the cell `11` and `13` other than `12` which means two horizontal rules made by `\hrule` are in the same line.

How can I do it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\fbox{\parbox{4in}{
    \makebox[\dimexpr 1in - 0.4pt][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{11}}%
    \vrule%
    \makebox[\dimexpr 2in - 0.4pt][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 2in - 2.4pt}{12}}%
    \vrule%
    \makebox[\dimexpr 1in - 0.4pt][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{13}}%
    \hrule width 1in \hspace{2in} \hrule width 1in %of cause this is a wrong way.
    \makebox[\dimexpr 1in - 0.4pt][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{21}}
}}
\end{document}
```

Second version:

I tried to use `\framebox` like this, but why is the cell`21` not at the second line? That is to say, why does it fail to feedline automatically?

```
\fbox{\parbox{4in}{\fboxsep3pt
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{11}}%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 2in][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 2in - 2.4pt}{12}}%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in}{13}}%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{21}}
  }}
```

Comment: same comment as last time. `\hrule` is a tex vertical mode primitive and so you can not have two on the same line. You could use the latex  `\rule` or use `\framebox` instead of `\makebox` and let latex add the rules.

Comment: I tried `framebox`, What causes the problem of my second version?

Comment: like all latex boxes, `\framebox` is positioned by the same logic as a letter and you have 4 in a row like `XXXX` with no space or linebreak specified so naturally you get 4 on the same line.

Comment: If the content `11` changes to `11\\11a`, the line fails to align horizontally. As the content of any cell can not be known in advance, any good idea for this problem?

Comment: you want all the parboxes to be `\parbox[t]`  if you want the boxes to align on top baseline

Comment: As each cell has frame, the bottom  rules of cells with different height of content are not aligned  on the same line which seems urgly. Can `\framebox` solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had specified no break points between the boxes. I believe the desired output is

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{4in}{\fboxsep3pt
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{11}}%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 2in][c]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr 2in - 2.4pt}{12}}%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr 1in}{13}}\\%
    \framebox[\dimexpr 1in][c]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr 1in - 2.4pt}{21}}
  }}
\end{document}
```